# ERROR IN TAKING INPUT IN JSF FORM

Tags: jsf

the login page is displaying "#{ad.userid}" in input text box  when loaded . I erased it and entered userid and pwd.when i clicked submit button the action method is called but the value in userid is being null in bean.could you resolve please.

Comment: please, title = title.toLowerCase();

Comment: exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254229/error-in-taking-input-in-jsf-form/3254511

Answer (score 1):

Do you have getter and setter method for your name property in your  bean?

Are they being call when you press submit button ?

Do you have all your components inside the `h:form`?
ex:-

```
<h:form>
<h:inputText value="#{mybean.name}" />
<h:commandButton value="CLICK" action="#{bean.method}" />
</h:form>
```

post your xhtml and bean